# Setting getSheetbyName according to cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm not much of a programmer but managed to cobbled together a script and can't seem to get the last part working. I want to pass activelog string into log and feel like it's a simple syntax issue I'm overlooking:

```
var activelog = e.source.getSheetByName("SHEET1").getRange("A1").getValue();
var log = e.source.getSheetByName(activelog);
```

Activelog gets the value of dropdown menu cell A1 on Sheet1 that contains list of all the relevant sheets. The script then copies down a formula in column C of whichever sheet is selected if something is typed in B1 of Sheet1. Right now specifying the sheetname "LOG" works fine:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var activelog = e.source.getSheetByName("SHEET1").getRange("A1").getValue();
    var log = e.source.getSheetByName("LOG");
    var lr = log.getLastRow();
    var fdr = log.getRange(1,23,lr);
    var formula = "";

    if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() !== "SHEET1" || e.range.rowStart != 1 || e.range.columnStart != 2 ) return
    log.getRange("C1").setFormula(formula);log.getRange("C1").copyTo(fdr);
}
```

Comment: B1 is a drop down menu that toggles the formula ON and OFF, but it also triggers filling down the formula incase new rows are added to the sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sheet is empty then `var lr = log.getLastRow()` will return a `0`. Then when the `log.getRange(1,23,lr)` tries to `getRange(1,23,0)` it will error as it is an invalid range.

Add `log.getLastRow() || 1;` to set `lr` to `1`, if the sheet is empty.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var activelog = e.source.getSheetByName("SHEET1").getRange("A1").getValue();
  var log = e.source.getSheetByName(activelog);

  // If getLastRow() returns 0, set 1
  var lr = log.getLastRow() || 1;
  var fdr = log.getRange(1,23,lr);

  var formula = "=SUM(1+2)"; // for testing

  if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() !== "SHEET1" || e.range.rowStart != 1 || e.range.columnStart != 2 ) return
  log.getRange("C1").setFormula(formula);log.getRange("C1").copyTo(fdr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `;` after your return in the last line.
Right now if the range is incorrect and it enters your condition, it does`return log.getRange("C1").setFormula(formula);`

And if it doesn't enter the if, all it does is `log.getRange("C1").copyTo(fdr);` without setting the formula first